# Javascript triggered CSS transition using transform and opacity not working in Firefox 71

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity, css-transforms

Using `Firefox 71.` 
I want to trigger a transition whereby the enter button (a tarted up div actually), `id=target`, slides in from the right and fades in at the same time.

The slide works perfectly but the opacity doesn't happen. Obviously I have to trigger this from `JavaScript` as the div is off of the screen so `pseudo class CSS` triggers are useless.

I've done this with an animation and `@keyframes` and it works great but I like the terseness of transitions. Any help and further assistance would be gratefully appreciated.
Steve

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Transition</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 48pt;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            #target{
                position: absolute;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                right: -212px;
                bottom: 200px;
                border: 6px solid darkblue;
                border-radius: 100px;
                opacity: 0;
                transition-property: transform, opacity;
                transition-duration: 1s;
                transition-timing-function: ease-in;
            }

            #inner_target{
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .start{
                transform: translateX(-412px);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="launch" type="button">Launch</button>

        <div id="target">
            <p id="inner_target">Enter</p>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            let launch = document.getElementById('launch');
            let target = document.getElementById('target');

            launch.addEventListener('click', startAnimation);

            function startAnimation(e) {
                target.classList.toggle('start');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of CSS specificity. You're using an ID `#target` to style your element, then apply a CSS class `start` to make it move and fade in. The original CSS block for `#target` contains a starting `opacity`, but no starting `transform`. After the `start` class is set, `transform` is set on the element and it moves. `opacity` is also set, but it has no effect. The reason is that the original `opacity` is set using an ID, and the new `opacity` is set using a class, and in CSS IDs are more specific than classes. Hence, the original `opacity` wins out and nothing happens.

Change your code to style your target element using a class rather than an ID:

```
<div id="target" class="mytarget">
  ...
</div>
```

and change the ID to a class in your CSS as well:

```
.mytarget {
  ...
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

Your `opacity` transition will now work ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/IndependentSw/pen/NWPvLMQ)).

Comment: Alexander, you are an absolute star. Because I'd used a mixture of transitions and animations I hadn't considered that transitions work solely with classes - is this so?

Comment: Transitions do work with IDs. However, it is mixing classes and IDs that introduced a specificity problem. I like working with mostly classes, using IDs only when I really need to grab an element from the DOM.